# Bullet Decal Sideways

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, raycasting

When I instantiate a bullet decal texture to the hit point of a raycast it goes sideways for some reason, no online resources have proved to be any help because it works for them.

The texture for the decal is on a plane and it is laying flat above the ground (height at which raycast hit.)

Here's the raycast shooting code:

```
var TheDammage = 100;
var BulletHole : Transform;
var canShoot : boolean;
var NoShootZoneTrigger : Transform;
//var AmmoText : GUIText;
var Ammo : float;
var MaxDistanceInMetersMax35 = 25;
var GunFirePistol : AudioClip;
var DryGunFirePistol : AudioClip;

function Start() {
    canShoot=true;
}
function Update () {
    if (MaxDistanceInMetersMax35>25){
        MaxDistanceInMetersMax35 = 35;
    }
    var hit : RaycastHit;
    var ray : Ray = 
    Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Vector3(Screen.width*0.5, Screen.height*0.5,0));
    //AmmoText.text = "Bullets Remaining: "+Ammo;

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)&& canShoot==true){
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, hit, 100)){
            if (Ammo >0){
                Ammo--;
                audio.PlayOneShot(GunFirePistol);
            }
            {
                Debug.Log(hit.distance);
                if (hit.distance<MaxDistanceInMetersMax35){
                    var particleClone = Instantiate(Effect, hit.point,
                    Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));
                    Destroy(particleClone.gameObject, 15);
                    hit.transform.SendMessage("ApplyDammage",
                    TheDammage, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                }
            }
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)&& canShoot==false){
                Debug.Log("No Shooting Zone!");
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("w")){
            canShoot = false;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp("w")){
            //animation.Play("GunWalkDone");
            canShoot=true;
        }
    }
    if (Ammo<1){
        canShoot=false;
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)&& canShoot==false){
            //AmmoText.text="";
            audio.PlayOneShot(DryGunFirePistol);
        }
    }
    if (Ammo<18) {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("r")){
            animation.Play("Reload");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not C#... or at least... the top half isn't.

Comment: Oops wrong tag :D meant to put JS

Comment: I learnt both languages so I mixed em up sorry bout that :D!

Comment: There's some mistake in the code after `audio.PlayOneShot(GunFirePistol);`: What's with the loose brackets? (`}{`)

Comment: `Instantiate(Effect, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));` this looks alright. Have you tried visualizing the directions of `hit.normal` with `Debug.Drawline`? Is it created sideways the same way all the time, or does it seem random?

Comment: Nope always the same at the height of raycast

Comment: What do you mean by 'at the height of raycast'? May be you could include the screenshot, so we can see how exactly this is sideways? May be it's your model that you use for decal is sideways?

Comment: No because I rotated the model portrait Ill take screen shot & show give me 2 secs

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/aw7osj/8 - Screenshot

Comment: I have rotated the plane that texture was on to the right angle then dragged it onto prefab and it turns out like this? I have adjusted rotation of prefab itself but it was of no help??

Comment: So what do I do next?